# My GTA 5 just stopped working

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My GTA 5 just stopped working. I'm already halfway finished with the game, and now all of a sudden, it just stops working. I tried reinstalling it, but that didn't work. It keeps coming up as an unrecognized disc. Plus, it's a brand new game so I don't get why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: Does the drive play other discs ok?

Comment: try washing the disk with warm water and liquid soap. Make sure you rinse it well and try it off before trying again

Comment: PS3 or 360? Do other games work? I would not recommend washing the disc with warm water and soap, until you have determined that the disc is the issue.

Answer (score -4):

What console are you playing on? If it is a PS3, just clean your Blueray lens or wash your disc. If it is an xbox360, try washing it. If you are playing on PC, maybe your PC has a virus.

Comment: GTA5 on PC. Sounds like you put a lot of thought into this one.

Comment: [GTA 5 will be released on PC in June of 2014.](http://crossmap.christianpost.com/news/gta-5-pc-release-date-in-june-amazon-reveals-version-excludes-windows-8-gta-san-andreas-mobile-release-is-rockstars-biggest-release-yet-9018)